# Adding a new point at user click while modifying an existing line or polygon geometry using Mapbox-gl-draw?

Tags: editing, linestring, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, map-drawing

I would like to have an edit option for my user to edit an existing line or polygon plotted in a map.
The edit option should allow user to add new vertices where user clicks.

I have tried using Mapbox-gl-draw plugin and it is working in a different way -> When editing the existing polygon/line, when I am clicking on the geometry I will get existing vertices and new vertices will appear at middle of existing points. I would like to have an option to add a new vertices at the point where I click while editing.

This is what I have tried:

HTML:

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.4/mapbox-gl-draw.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-draw/v1.0.4/mapbox-gl-draw.css' type='text/css' />
<div id='map'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'https://maputnik.github.io/osm-liberty/style.json',
  center: [79.30961608886719, 61.57192958204744],
  zoom: 10,
  hash: true
});

var Draw = new MapboxDraw({
  userProperties: true,
  styles: [{
      id: 'highlight-active-points',
      type: 'circle',
      filter: ['all',
        ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
        ['==', 'meta', 'feature'],
        ['==', 'active', 'true']
      ],
      paint: {
        'circle-radius': 0.1,
        'circle-color': '#D20C0C'
      }

    },
    {
      id: 'points-are-blue',
      type: 'circle',
      filter: ['all',
        ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
        ['==', 'meta', 'feature'],
        ['==', 'active', 'false']
      ],
      paint: {
        'circle-radius': 5,
        'circle-color': '#D20C0C'
      }
    },
    // ACTIVE (being drawn)
    // line stroke
    {
      id: 'gl-draw-line',
      type: 'line',
      filter: ['all', ['==', '$type', 'LineString'],
        ['!=', 'mode', 'static']
      ],
      layout: {
        'line-cap': 'round',
        'line-join': 'round'
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#D20C0C',
        'line-width': 3
      }
    },
    // polygon fill
    {
      id: 'gl-draw-polygon-fill',
      type: 'fill',
      filter: ['all', ['==', '$type', 'Polygon'],
        ['!=', 'mode', 'static']
      ],
      paint: {
        'fill-color': '#120404',
        'fill-outline-color': '#120404',
        'fill-opacity': 0.1
      }
    },
    // polygon outline stroke
    // This doesn't style the first edge of the polygon, which uses the line stroke styling instead
    {
      id: 'gl-draw-polygon-stroke-active',
      type: 'line',
      filter: ['all', ['==', '$type', 'Polygon'],
        ['!=', 'mode', 'static']
      ],
      layout: {
        'line-cap': 'round',
        'line-join': 'round'
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#D20C0C',
        'line-width': 2
      }
    },
    // vertex points
    {
      id: 'gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active',
      type: 'circle',
      filter: ['all', ['==', 'meta', 'vertex'],
        ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
        ['!=', 'mode', 'static']
      ],
      paint: {
        'circle-radius': 3,
        'circle-color': '#D20C0C',
      }
    },
    {
      'id': 'gl-draw-polygon-midpoint',
      'type': 'circle',
      'filter': ['all', ['==', '$type', 'Point'],
        ['==', 'meta', 'midpoint']
      ],
      'paint': {
        'circle-radius': 6,
        'circle-color': '#D20C0C',
      }
    },

  ]
});
map.addControl(Draw, 'top-left');

map.on('load', (e) => {
  Draw.set(geoJSON)
});

var geoJSON = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "class_id": 1
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              79.30961608886719,
              61.57192958204744
            ],
            [
              79.34309005737303,
              61.57192958204744
            ],
            [
              79.34309005737303,
              61.57871162332267
            ],
            [
              79.30961608886719,
              61.57871162332267
            ],
            [
              79.30961608886719,
              61.57192958204744
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "class_id": 2
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              79.35201644897461,
              61.58271478278019
            ],
            [
              79.35115814208984,
              61.573972521656835
            ],
            [
              79.38188552856444,
              61.57192958204744
            ],
            [
              79.3956184387207,
              61.581080902573085
            ],
            [
              79.37124252319336,
              61.58973948654749
            ],
            [
              79.35201644897461,
              61.58271478278019
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          79.41947937011719,
          61.58630901615167
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            79.3733024597168,
            61.56302079282452
          ],
          [
            79.42153930664062,
            61.57078547708563
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              79.32952880859375,
              61.55893333624483
            ],
            [
              79.36197280883789,
              61.55893333624483
            ],
            [
              79.36197280883789,
              61.56481910315267
            ],
            [
              79.32952880859375,
              61.56481910315267
            ],
            [
              79.32952880859375,
              61.55893333624483
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sreejithvelath/sx8o7k9r/25/

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: I have added more details and also provided the code

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this. Could anyone help here.